# *.svc/js returning outdated javascript file

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have deployed an ASP.net enabled WCF service but the javascript returned by the service is outdated.
Do I have to manually refresh it?

Comment: Could you more further explain your question, perhaps with snippets of the returned vs expected javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is not allowed to move the cs files outside to App_Code folder